# POST request side-effects on RESTful API

Tags: rest, api, http, post

I'm building an API that enables clients to send emails to their subscribers. It may be that the subscriber is already registered with an unique id assigned to it. Therefore, a `POST /emails/subscribers/:subcriberId` endpoint exists that lets the client send an email to the subscriber identified by `subscriberId`.

Now, a new use case has arisen where a email may be sent to a unregistered subscriber. Instead, the email and the name of it will be specified in the request body.

I'm thinking to implement the following endpoint:

```
POST /emails
{
    // email content and metadata
    "receiverName": "John Smith",
    "receiverEmail": "john@example.com"
}
```

It will be nice to use the receiver's data to *create* a new subscriber for future actions. But this would be a *side effect* of sending the email.

**Is this an acceptable RESTful practice?**

*Notes*:

- I want to avoid the client having first to create the subscriber and the sending the email.
- Subscribers are also uniquely identified by email.

Comment: You also could edit the original method to have optional suscriberId and add the other optionals parameters to the body, and in your backend decide what to do based on what parameters you get

Comment: That raises another question: How to document mutually exclusive parameters in the REST architecture? Using OpenAPI 3.0 specifically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this an acceptable RESTful practice?

Yes.

HTTP constraints the semantics of the request and the response.  Implementation side effects are at the discretion of the server.

Comment: Any source for this?

Comment: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html
https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.3

Answer (score 0):

One way to get around your problem is to provide a `POST /emails` endpoint whose contract supports both use cases: send emails to subscribers and non-subscribers.

Regarding your API, I suggest you rethink your design as it violates some basic design principles.  For instance:

- collection resource names should be plural (i.e., `/subscribers`)
- you should review the has-a relationships between your resources (i.e., a subscriber has an email, not the other way around).

Comment: First point: Yes, the resources name in singular were a typo. 
Second point: Are you refering to `/emails/subcribers/:id` vs `/subscribers/:id/email`? I thought it the first way because the action was to POST an email to a subscriber. Does it makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

If the POST here is associated to the standard CREATE method I think this is actually a side effect. Storing the email is not a side-effect but connecting to a SMTP server and send an email to a any recipient it is.